# Issue with timestamp format when trying to create my K8S cluster in AWS using a script

Tags: timestamp, jq, yq

I try and run the script and i get the below error

> jq: error (at :1): date "2021-09-07T08:29:29Z" does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

My script has this line which I guess is what causes the error

```
yq '.metadata.creationTimestamp |= (. | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))' | \
```

I didn't write the script so I don't really know what that line means exactly. Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong? Is it a local issue with my timestamp format?

Comment: Your command shows `yg`, but the error is about `jq`?

Comment: @0stone0 There are two versions of yq, one of them is built upon jq. Apparently OP is using that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the given date-time string does not match the given format.
This is because the former has a trailing "Z", which is not accounted for in the latter.

For example, using jq, we see:

```
$ jq -ncM '"2021-09-07T08:29:29Z"|strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")'
[2021,8,7,8,29,29,2,249]
```

So you could delete the "Z" in the date-time string  (e.g. by sub("Z$";"")), or add it in the format string, as shown in the example.

Comment: cool thanks. But since the the trailing Z is actually coming from the timezone of my local machine ( which is mac) i'd have to find a way to edit the timestamp format on my machine right?

Comment: It would probably be easier to change the jq script, which could also be made more tolerant (i.e., accepting of both formats).